# Configure SSH credentials per environment

Tags: ssh, ansible

I'm trying to figure out how to configure the SSH credentials separately for a production and staging environment with Ansible. I understand that you can configure the server IP addresses and hostnames separately using different inventory files by passing the `-i` or `--inventory-file` argument to the `ansible-playbook` command. However, I see no such option for `ansible.cfg`. Currently, the credentials live in `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` as:

```
[defaults]
private_key_file=/home/caleb/.ssh/staging_key.pem
remote_user=ubuntu
sudo_user=root
gathering=explicit
```

How can I configure multiple SSH credentials, one for production and one for staging?

Comment: what changes between your environments? Just the key file, or also the remote_user/sudo_user?

Comment: @tedder42 The SSH private key and remote_user.

Comment: Why don't you cover that in your .ssh/config?

Comment: @udondan Is there a way to specify a single key once for multiple hosts in `.ssh/config`?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. You can create multiple groups with explicit hostnames or patterns. Let me post an example in an answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Seems like my first answer was not entirely correct. While of course it is possible to solve it in your `.ssh/config` like described below, it seems as well to be possible with Ansibles [Behavioral Inventory Parameters](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters).

You should (according to docs) be able to define the keyfile and the user in your inventory, either per host or per group.

Definition per group:

```
[some_hosts]
host1.foo
host2.foo

[some_hosts:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/caleb/.ssh/staging_key.pem
```

Definition per host:

```
[some_hosts]
host1.foo     ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu          ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/caleb/.ssh/staging_key.pem
host2.foo     ansible_ssh_user=another_user    ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/caleb/.ssh/production_key.pem
```

---

But you can define multiple host groups already in your `.ssh/config` and each group can have their separate settings regarding key and user.

Here is a quick example

```
#Example with a wildcard
Host *.foo.com
  user ubuntu
  IdentityFile /home/caleb/.ssh/staging_key.pem

#Example with multiple hostnames
Host hostname.one hostname.two hostname.three
  user other_user
  IdentityFile /home/caleb/.ssh/production_key.pem
```

As well you could define a default and override it later with more detailed settings.

```
Host *
  user defaut_username

Host somehost
  user special_username
```